# parse DataFrame which has special symbols &

Tags: python, dataframe

Could you help me? I have `DataFrame`:

```
column1  column2
    0        house_id=678&referrer_id=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru&source_id=google_ru
    1        referrer_id=https%12A%2G%2Fyandex.ru&house_id=18&source_id=facebook_ru
    2        referrer_id=https%88U%3D%2Wwild.ru&source_id=vk_ru&house_id=9
    3        referrer_id=https%88U%3D%2Wwild.ru&source_id=vk_ru
```

I want to get "house_id" like this:

```
column1  column2
        0        678
        1        18
        2        9
        3        0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is a solution that will get you your answer, but it is not the most efficient way to get there. Nonetheless, using `str.split` to split your messy column, and then extracting the digits with `str.extract`:

```
import pandas as pd

df[['p1','p2']] = df['column2'].str.split('house_id',expand=True)
df['house_id'] =  (df['p2'].str.split('&').str[0].str.extract('(\d+)')).fillna(0)
res = df[['column1','house_id']]
```

Will give you your desired output:

```
res

Out[24]: 
   column1 house_id
0        0      678
1        1       18
2        2        9
3        3        0
```